# Change SVG fill color on hover isn't working

Tags: css, svg, hover, fill

I am trying to change the color of an SVG image when hovering but it seems that I cannot make it work.

Here's the code:

```css
.signup-icon {
  fill: #515151;
}

.signup-icon:hover {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<svg class="signup-icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M19.6977 8.82624L10.6068 0.64442C10.4398 0.493657 10.2227 0.410156 9.99769 0.410156C9.77267 0.410156 9.55566 0.493657 9.38862 0.64442L0.297707 8.82624C0.128761 8.97975 0.0237846 9.19113 0.00357345 9.4185C-0.0166377 9.64588 0.0493999 9.87259 0.188621 10.0535C0.23709 10.1277 0.29872 10.1923 0.37045 10.2444C0.527528 10.3541 0.715218 10.4114 0.906783 10.408H2.72496V17.6808C2.72496 17.9219 2.82076 18.153 2.99124 18.3235C3.16173 18.494 3.39295 18.5899 3.63406 18.5899H16.3613C16.6024 18.5899 16.8337 18.494 17.0042 18.3235C17.1747 18.153 17.2704 17.9219 17.2704 17.6808V10.408H19.0886C19.2802 10.4114 19.4679 10.3541 19.625 10.2444C19.6967 10.1923 19.7583 10.1277 19.8068 10.0535C19.8728 9.96969 19.9222 9.87397 19.9522 9.77162C20.0045 9.60616 20.0082 9.42923 19.9631 9.2617C19.918 9.09417 19.826 8.94311 19.6977 8.82624ZM13.6341 16.7717H4.54315V9.49896C4.54315 9.25785 4.44741 9.02658 4.27692 8.85609C4.10643 8.6856 3.87516 8.58987 3.63406 8.58987H3.27955L9.99769 2.54439L16.7159 8.58987H16.3613C16.1202 8.58987 15.889 8.6856 15.7185 8.85609C15.548 9.02658 15.4522 9.25785 15.4522 9.49896V16.7717H13.6341Z"/>
    </svg>
```

I've tried adding `!important` but it doesn't work. Even the property when not hovered isn't taken in account.
Although, if I put some inline style on the SVG with the fill property, then it works. But I still cannot manage to make the hovering effect work.

Comment: seems to [work](https://jsfiddle.net/ocL8v5u2/), editing the post into code snippet also works, but then it seems to counter the question

Comment: Your svg is transparent in the middle, so it changes just the border.

Comment: do you just need to set pointer-events="all"

Comment: Indeed it is working in the snippet but I still don't understand why it doesn't work in my browser.
I've set the pointer-events to all and it didn't change anything.
And if the svg is transparent in the middle, how can I solve this to make it work?

Comment: @TimothyCohen could be a z-index problem or a pointer-events problem as mentioned, however, we're unable to help you unless you post the full code

Comment: Most likely it is either: (a) you have another CSS rule that is overriding your hover rule, or (b) another element is on top of your icon and is preventing it receiving mouse events. But again **add a [mcve] that shows the problem**.  Without that we can only make stabs in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, however, it's pretty hard to see due to the white background and the white color you set on hover.

```css
.signup-icon {
  fill: red;
}

.signup-icon:hover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg class="signup-icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M19.6977 8.82624L10.6068 0.64442C10.4398 0.493657 10.2227 0.410156 9.99769 0.410156C9.77267 0.410156 9.55566 0.493657 9.38862 0.64442L0.297707 8.82624C0.128761 8.97975 0.0237846 9.19113 0.00357345 9.4185C-0.0166377 9.64588 0.0493999 9.87259 0.188621 10.0535C0.23709 10.1277 0.29872 10.1923 0.37045 10.2444C0.527528 10.3541 0.715218 10.4114 0.906783 10.408H2.72496V17.6808C2.72496 17.9219 2.82076 18.153 2.99124 18.3235C3.16173 18.494 3.39295 18.5899 3.63406 18.5899H16.3613C16.6024 18.5899 16.8337 18.494 17.0042 18.3235C17.1747 18.153 17.2704 17.9219 17.2704 17.6808V10.408H19.0886C19.2802 10.4114 19.4679 10.3541 19.625 10.2444C19.6967 10.1923 19.7583 10.1277 19.8068 10.0535C19.8728 9.96969 19.9222 9.87397 19.9522 9.77162C20.0045 9.60616 20.0082 9.42923 19.9631 9.2617C19.918 9.09417 19.826 8.94311 19.6977 8.82624ZM13.6341 16.7717H4.54315V9.49896C4.54315 9.25785 4.44741 9.02658 4.27692 8.85609C4.10643 8.6856 3.87516 8.58987 3.63406 8.58987H3.27955L9.99769 2.54439L16.7159 8.58987H16.3613C16.1202 8.58987 15.889 8.6856 15.7185 8.85609C15.548 9.02658 15.4522 9.25785 15.4522 9.49896V16.7717H13.6341Z"/>
    </svg>
```